# Calculate the contract address created using create2 with dynamic byte string as a salt

Tags: solidity, bytes, create2, salt

[EIP-1014](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1014.md) describes salt as `bytes32`.
However, the function `create2` written in assembly allows passing byte string of arbitrary size as the `salt` parameter.

*Example*

```
function deploy(bytes memory bytecode, bytes memory _salt) public payable {
    address addr;

    /*
    NOTE: How to call create2

    create2(v, p, n, s)
    create new contract with code at memory p to p + n
    and send v wei
    and return the new address
    where new address = first 20 bytes of keccak256(0xff + address(this) + s + keccak256(mem[p…(p+n)))
          s = big-endian 256-bit value
    */
    assembly {
        addr := create2(
            callvalue(), // wei sent with current call
            // Actual code starts after skipping the first 32 bytes
            add(bytecode, 0x20),
            mload(bytecode), // Load the size of code contained in the first 32 bytes
            _salt // Salt from function arguments
        )

        if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
    }

    emit Deployed(addr, _salt);
}
```

How to precompute deployed contract address in that case?

This function works for `bytes32` salt, but gives incorrect result here.

```
function getAddress(
    bytes memory bytecode,
    bytes memory _salt
) public view returns (address) {
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(
        abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xff), address(this), _salt, keccak256(bytecode))
    );

    // NOTE: cast last 20 bytes of hash to address
    return address(uint160(uint(hash)));
}
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

In reality, the `salt` that `create2 OPCODE` accepts is supposed to be a `uint256` value:

> create new contract with code mem[p…(p+n)) at address keccak256(0xff .
> this . s . keccak256(mem[p…(p+n))) and send v wei and return the new
> address, where 0xff is a 1 byte value, this is the current contract’s
> address as a 20 byte value and **s is a big-endian 256-bit value**;
> returns 0 on error (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/yul.html)

---

However, *if for some particular reason you want to accept this `salt` value in a *dynamically-sized* `bytes` format*, you can use the following **code snippet** that I prepared:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Account {
    string public description;

    constructor() {
        description = "";
    }
}

contract Test {
    event Deployed(address /*indexed*/ outcomeAddress, uint256 /*indexed*/ salt);

    function deploy(bytes memory bytecode, bytes memory saltBytes) internal returns (address) {
        address addr;

        uint256 salt;

        assembly {
            salt := mload(add(saltBytes, add(0x20, 0))) // load saltInt from the saltBytes, it's not just explicitly referencing saltBytes
            // in the create2 call, but really loading the first 32 bytes
            // Loading the first 32 bytes because a uint value can never be more than 256 bits
            // ==> meaning 32 bytes IS PLENTY
        }

        assembly {
            addr := create2(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode), salt)

            if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }

        emit Deployed(addr, salt);

        return addr;
    }

    function getAddress(
        bytes memory bytecode,
        bytes memory salt
    ) internal view returns (address) {
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xff), address(this), salt, keccak256(bytecode))
        );

        // NOTE: cast last 20 bytes of hash to address
        return address(uint160(uint(hash)));
    }

    function performTestDeploy(uint256 saltInt) external returns (address deploymentAddress) {
        bytes memory saltBytes = toBytes(saltInt);

        bytes memory byteCode = abi.encodePacked(type(Account).creationCode);

        return deploy(byteCode, saltBytes);

    }

    function performTestGetAndCompare(uint256 saltInt) external view returns (address create2GeneratedAddress) {
        bytes memory bytesSalt = toBytes(saltInt);

        return getAddress(abi.encodePacked(type(Account).creationCode), bytesSalt);
    }

    function toBytes(uint256 x) internal pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodePacked(x); // convert (uint --> bytes) for testing
    }
}
```

... **Which gives the following result:**

[image: result-create2-compute-precompute-address-bytes-dynamic-1]

---

**Some comments:**

- Loading the first 32 bytes is plenty, because a UINT value can never be `> 256 bits` *(€ **32 bytes**)*

---

Hopefully, that answers your question!!